# USB Camera crashes when opening Serial Port

Tags: c#, camera, serial-port, windows-10, emgucv

I'm writing a program in WPF that needs to connect to a serial port to get and send data to a piece of machinery, and connect to a camera mounted on the machinery to show the video stream.

So last week we bought a mini PC (a beelink bt3 pro) to give to our customers when they bought this machinery, so they could install our program on this dedicated pc.
We immediately noticed that on the program startup, the camera would crash with that notorious sound that windows makes when you disconnect an usb device.
So after searching for clues on the problem I found out that when I called serialport.Open(), the camera would crash. For the serial port I use the standard Microsoft library, while for the camera I first used Directshow, then EMGUCV (I switched last week because i tought that the problem was caused by the camera library).

This is the code I use in the test program:

```
VideoCapture c = new VideoCapture(0);
c.ImageGrabbed += c_ImageGrabbed;
c.Start();
SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM5", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.None); 
port.Open();
```

Just after calling Open(), the camera crashes and stops recording, making the windows error sound like it was removed from the PC. No Exceptions are thrown out, and the program keeps running.

It is important to notice that this problem happens only on this PC, and I have the doubt that Windows 10 was not installed correctly, as I found a Windows.old folder in C:, and the system prompts me sometimes to delete the old windows folder.

Comment: `Windows.old` can be due to an upgrade/major update: it's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Does it crash with an exception? Does it crash without the camera? Are there any shared resources between the hardware (like COM port).

Comment: Is the camera powered over USB? Can you exclude a power problem?

Comment: @Stefan no exceptions are thrown. It doesn't crash the program. Without a camera there are no errors when calling Open(). Seems as like they share some resources as you said but I don't know how to tell.

Comment: @KlausGütter yes it is. How can I check if there is a power problem?

Comment: @KlausGütter: wow... that would be a nice find.

Comment: @MarcoFilippozzi: you can test it with an external powered usb hub.

Comment: As for shared resources, these day's its extremely rare to have same IRQ or post numbers. -- it more something from the stone ages. The only possibility I can see is that the camera is emulating a COM5 in a way, but still.... that's highly unlikely because it wouldn't result in a hardware crash but in a "port busy" exception. You could google on the IRQ stuff... but if you havn't done BIOS or IRQ/PORT/DMA related stuff, that should be fine.

Comment: At this point I will have to try @KlausGütter theory. But how possible is it? I mean shouldn't other PCs give this problem too?

Comment: Can you try to open the port with HyperTerminal or Putty, or some other terminal program?

Comment: @KlausGütter Hi klaus, in the end we tried your idea, and it resulted to be true. Using an externally powered usb hub proved to work. If you want to post your idea as an answer I would be happy to accept it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the camera is powered over USB, it is probably a power problem, i.e. the USB port on the computer does not deliver enough current for a stable operation of the camera.

You may try

- to connect the camara to a USB port with higher current specification
- to connect the camera over an externally powered USB Hub.